# Where am I going wrong: verifying a solution to a non-homogenous difference equation

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, first-order-logic, homogeneous-equation

I am trying to verify a solution I have found to a non-homogeneous difference equation. However, when I substitute this solution into both sides of the difference equation, the two sides are not equal. They are slightly off. Where am I going wrong in the process? Is my solution incorrect? Please see the attached photo below:[image]

[image]

Comment: Top line, left side: plug in $x_{n+1}$, not $x_n$.

Comment: May I suggest an alternative approach, let $x_n = y_n + c$, and find the value of $c$ that makes the problem easy to solve.

Comment: @BoLe once I do that, what do I do then? I'm left with and xn term stuck there...

and thanks Daniel! I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately I must substitute.

Comment: Look, $x_n$ has term raised to $n$, so $x_{n+1}$ has got to have the same term raised to $n+1$. Now, to verify, plug the latter into lhs and the former to rhs of the equation.

Comment: I'm left with:
2/5xn + 2/5 = 2/5(-1/6(2/5)^n + 2/3) + 2/5

How does that prove that they're equal? Sorry, I'm not the best at mathematics.

Comment: You plugged equation into the equation. ;-) You must plug the solutions into the equation. Solution for $x_n$ is before your eyes. Solution for $x_{n+1}$ you must still conjure up .... how, well, by replacing occurrences of $n$ with $n+1$ of course.

Comment: So the solution for xn is = -1/6(2/5)^n + 2/3  and the solution for xn+1 is 2/5(n+1) + 2/5 ?

Comment: No, that looks like the equation, solution is $x_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{6} (\frac{2}{5})^{n+1} + \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: I do...I'm just confused. There are so many equations. Am I subbing in xn+1 into the left and then what am I subbing into the right? xn = -1/6(2/5)^n + 2/3?

Comment: Would you be able to show me on paper or something?
So the solution that I found (the one in my photo) is incorrect? The n should be n+1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43933/discussion-between-bole-and-indifferent-potato).

Comment: Sure, let's do that then.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't understand what a sequence is. It is just a special kind of **function**, and in your case its domain is $\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$$\nn$. Your recurrence relation says $x(n+1) = \frac25 x(n) + \frac25$ for every $n \in \nn$. Your solution says $x(n) = -\frac16 (\frac25)^n + \frac23$ for every $n \in \nn$. To check that the solution works, you just need to compute $x(n+1)$ and $\frac25 x(n) + \frac25$ **according to the solution** for $n \in \nn$ and check that they are equal.

Note that "$x(n) = -\frac16 (\frac25)^n + \frac23$ for every $n \in \nn$" says the same as "$x(k) = -\frac16 (\frac25)^k + \frac23$ for every $k \in \nn$", and means that we can put in any $k$ we like as long as $k \in \nn$, and the equation will hold. For example $x(7) = -\frac16 (\frac25)^7 + \frac23$, because $7 \in \nn$. Now you want $x(n+1)$ where $n \in \nn$, right? $n+1 \in \nn$, so what is $x(n+1)$?